# how can i design for android multiple screens most exactly for Galaxy Nexus (720x1280) and Nexus 4(768x1280)?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, screen-size, display

I am developing an application using density criteria, but when I compare my layout in those screens Galaxy Nexus (720x1280) and Nexus 4 (768x1280), the former is fine and in the latter there is a white space on the left side.
I use dp to scale the layout and the 2 layout have the same density (xhdpi).

So how can I design different layout with the same density and screen size?

Here is a sample code to create an xhdpi layout an use Android Studio preview in these 2 phones to see the next picture.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="dimx"
    android:layout_height="dimy"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

dimens file in the xhdpi folder

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dimx">360dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dimy">512dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

dimens file in the other folder

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="@dimen/dimx">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="@dimen/dimy">0dp</dimen>
```

[image: Nexus 4 layout]

[image: Galaxy Nexus layout]

Comment: What do you use "dimx" and "dimy" for?

Comment: to use one layout and set the size depending the density of the screen
but now i see that two screen with the same density can have different dp
if you know a better form to support multi screen tell me because i got this way reading google developer support. and i was reading but the only good way is using weight but i need some way to make a square shape in different screen and weight is not enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in your xml is `android:layout_width="@dimen/dimx"` and     `android:layout_height="@dimen/dimy"`

**Edit:** Google Nexus and Nexus 4 have *different screen width* and you use hardcoded dimensions, this is the main problem. To avoid any future problem use relative value instead of hardcoded value, in your case setting match_parent will solve your issue.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: this was a writting error but is not related with the problem